# Ducktyping with exception objects

Tags: python

I want to create a function that can check if the passed arg is an Exception or one of its subclasses. As an example, I would like the the second is_exception function call to return True as well.

```
def is_exception(obj):
    return type(obj) == Exception

print is_exception(Exception('asdf'))   => True
print is_exception(EOFError('asdf'))    => False
```

thanks!

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to do this. What's your actual use case?

Comment: Does `EOFError` subclass `Exception` or `BaseException`?

Comment: @jamylak: EOFError is a subclass of Exception which is a subclass of BaseException.

Comment: Oh nvm my bad, i forgot it was built-in :$

Comment: DanieL: I have a logger that I want to pass in a bunch of common objects along with the message. The logger looks at the args and does different things depending on what was passed in. I guess I could have used kwargs, but I want the function call to be as minimal as possible. Like so: log_error('an error occured', exception, user, some_other_common_object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use issubclass:

```
>>> issubclass(EOFError,Exception)
True
>>> issubclass(EOFError,EOFerror)
True
```

The signature is "issubclass(A,B)" which will return True if A is a subclass of B, or "issubclass(A,(B1,B2...))" which will return True if A is a subclass of any of B1,B2 etc.